# Databricks - Spark is not counting table number of rows after union

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to open a lot of parquet files and get one column for those parquet files.

I did a loop to get this field, and I apply the following function:

```
  if 'attribute_name' in spark.read.parquet(p[0]).columns:
    i=i+1
    table = spark.read.parquet(p[0]).\
        select('attribute_name').distinct().withColumn('Path',F.lit(element[0]))
    k = k+table.count()  

if i == 1:
    table1 = table
  else:
    table1 = table1.union(table)
```

I created i and k only to counting purposes, i is the number of files and k is the total of number of rows. element is an element of a list of paths (the list of all the files).

According my countings I read 457 parquet files, and I got in total 21,173 different rows (for all the parquet files).

When I try to count directly in the table1 (with table1.count()) the number of rows I got the following [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvbFL.png):
Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 4932 tasks (4.0 GiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize 4.0 GiB.

To be honest I don't understand what is happening and I don't have idea how to solve it, I tried repartition over table1 after the union and it's not working. Do you have some ideas to how to solve it?

Comment: By the way, the same error I got when I try to push the data into a different SQL Server. :(

Comment: Hard to say with the provided info, but generally better to not do an action (count) in your loop (you can get the total count from table1.count() anyway). Also the distinct is probably better after all the unions, result should be the same if you have unique paths.

Comment: @ScootCork thanks for your answer!! I completely understand your point, however I did it because I want to push the data in SQL and I got the same ERROR. It's easier explain the issue with the count, and not with the jdbc connection. :( I have been struggling with this issue in the past days and I don't have idea on how to solve it.